# ServiceStack CORS setup fails due to response to pre-flight doesn't pass access control check

Tags: servicestack

We're trying to set up ServiceStack and CORS within our test environment.  Currently there is no IIS security set up (anonymous).  When trying to connect from the client (React) the request is rejected with

"Access to fetch at 'https://xxx?format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

We've tried the below to set up ServiceStack but we're unsure if this is a server setup issue or a client setup issue.

```
Here's my request:

const https = require("https");

function deleteStaffMember(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.name)
  try {
    const res = fetch(`https://xxx/${e.currentTarget.name}?format=json`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      agent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }),
      credentials: 'omit'
    })
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Here are the AppHost service stack attempts, from current to previous attempts:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    //Permit modern browsers (e.g. Firefox) to allow sending of any HTTP Method
    SetConfig(new HostConfig 
    {
        GlobalResponseHeaders = {
          { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" },
          { "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" },
          { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" },
        },
    });
}
```

**earlier:**

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist: *,
    allowCredentials: false,
    allowedHeaders: *));
```

**even earlier:**

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist: new[] { "http://localhost","http://localhost:3000" },
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, X-Args"));
```

**original:**

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature());
```

**EDIT**
Here's my DELETE (I assume this doesn't get as much because it's the pre-flight request):

DELETE /NDBServiceStack/staff/hierarchy/1315
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/index
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15

Comment: Can up update your question to include the raw HTTP Request/Response Headers, using something like Fiddler or Chrome Web Inspector.

Answer (score 1):

After working more with mythz we have resolved this issue.  I found both server and client side changes needed to be made to resolve the issue.  Here are the requirements for IIS 10 in our instance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your Request needs cookies, i.e. relies on Sessions for Authentication they need to be included in the JS `fetch()` request and I'd also specify the [mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode) to allow CORS requests, e.g:

```
const res = fetch(`https://xxx/${e.currentTarget.name}?format=json`, {
  method: 'DELETE',
  agent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }),
  mode: 'cors',
  credentials: 'include'
})
```

Your [Access-Control-Allow-Origin whitelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) should then explicitly include the origin you want to allow which from your description may be `http://localhost:3000`:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(
    allowOriginWhitelist: new[] { "http://localhost:3000" },
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization, X-Args"));
```

Comment: We still get the same result and header information.  Are we fighting ourselves where the service stack is deployed to a test server with org url and the React project is just sitting on a developer box running localhost:3000?